# Can't connect to VPN L2TP from Ubuntu 18.04 CLI

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, nmcli, l2tp

I have a VPN that is working when I connect through my windows using L2TP, however when I set up my ubuntu with CLI its not working. I get the following error when I run

```
$ nmcli c up myvpn
```

Error output

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection.
```

### What I've tried

- disabled the firewall `sudo ufw disable`
- created the vpn configuration with

```
nmcli connection add connection.id myvpn con-name myvpn type VPN vpn-type l2tp ifname -- connection.autoconnect no ipv4.method auto vpn.data "gateway = x.x.x.x, ipsec-enabled = yes, ipsec-psk = 0s"$(base64 <<<'psk***psk' | rev | cut -c2- | rev)"=, mru = 1400, mtu = 1400, password-flags = 0, refuse-chap = yes, refuse-mschap = yes, refuse-pap = yes, require-mppe = yes, user = username" vpn.secrets password=mypassword
```

- NetworkManager is managing the following interfaces

```
user@ubunut:~# nmcli device status
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
eth0     ethernet  connected  eth0
docker0  bridge    connected  docker0
lo       loopback  unmanaged  --
```

- list all NM connections: `nmcli con`

```
NAME             UUID                     TYPE      DEVICE
docker0          ef3eb3a8-c46e-434c-bfcb  bridge    docker0
eth0             fc920355-d18e-495a-b3ca  ethernet  eth0
myvpn            2b24ce55-98d3-4bc0-8b52  vpn       --
Ifupdown (eth0)  681b428f-beaf-8932-dce4  ethernet  --
```

Still I'm not able to connect and I'm stuck now. I don't know what else to do to make it work. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

nmcli usage :

- list all NM connections: `nmcli con`
- bring up VPN connection : `nmcli con up id myvpn`
- bring down VPN connection: `nmcli con down id myvpn`

Where *myvpn* is the actual name of the VPN connection as listed in the nmcli con output.

Use `nmcli con reload` whenever a new VPN connection profile file (usually located under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/) has been created or has been edited, so Networkmanager will notice the change. Although it might not be needed with `nmcli con add`

You were using `nmcli con up myvpn` instead of `nmcli con up id myvpn`, the former requires the VPN connection's UUID.

For a bit of simplicity, you can use a clear text PSK instead of a base64 one starting with `0s`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm still getting the same error when I use `nmcli con up id myvpn`. The list looks like this

NAME             UUID                     TYPE      DEVICE
docker0          ef3eb3a8-c46e-434c-bfcb  bridge    docker0
eth0             fc920355-d18e-495a-b3ca  ethernet  eth0
myvpn          2b24ce55-98d3-4bc0-8b52  vpn       --
Ifupdown (eth0)  681b428f-beaf-8932-dce4  ethernet  --

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Could not find source connection` suggests you have configured a specific NetworkManager connection that would be used as the foundation for the VPN connection, and that connection cannot be found.

If you configured the VPN connection with:

```
nmcli connection add [...] ifname -- [...]
```

then the `ifname --` part is probably wrong: if you want to use the VPN without restricting the network interface(s) the VPN may use, just omit the `ifname --` part entirely. If you want to only use the VPN with a particular network interface, then you might specify e.g. `ifname eth0` here.